# Why the grid do no changed when I change the search condition and read the grid again?How to set the grid no cache?

Tags: caching, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My grid is called grid1,When I input the condition like start date and end date ,and then click the search button,sometimes the grid1 changed,but sometimes the grid1 do not change.I think may be due to  the cache.How to set the grid no cache?

```
$("#grid1").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

I try to write like this,but it seems wrong.

```
$("#grid1").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read().cache(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use asp.net mvc,you can add a nocache to controlloer.

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
 public class AppController : Controller{}
```